# Max Stack exceeded error, how would I fix this?

Tags: javascript, recursion, stack-overflow

I am making a function that returns true if number in outerfucntion is within innerfunction list

```
<script>
function hasMatch(item) {
    hasMatch(2)  
    function inList() {
        var List = [1,2,3,4];
        for (i = 0; i<List.length; i++){
            if (list[i] == item) { 
                return true; 
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    inList();
}
hasMatch();
</script>
```

I get a "Max Stack exceeded error", how would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasMatch(2)` is recursive call without any terminating condition.

`hasMatch()` is getting called infinitely and that's why you see stack exceeded error.

```
function hasMatch(item) { 
    function inList() {
        var List = [1,2,3,4];
        for (i = 0; i<List.length; i++){
            if (List[i] == item) { 
                return true; 
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return inList();
}

hasMatch(2);
```

Comment: how and where do i add a terminating condition?